# Issues using an Apple Thunderbolt display with PC. Not working as expected

Tags: mac

Picked up a fully functional 27" Apple Thunderbolt display and would like to use with my PC.

Understanding the Apple Thunderbolt display needs to be connected with Thunderbolt port I pulled video card, (NVIDIA GeForce 9500 GT) from Mac Pro and added to my PC.

Video card is recognized and works when connecting HP monitor to PC, (MDP to Display port Cable)

Used same cable to go from Mac Pro to Dell monitor just to confirm cable works on both machines to Dell Monitor.

Tested Apple Thunderbolt monitor’s built-on Thunderbolt cable to Mac Pro and confirmed it works. Tried the same cable to the PC with NVIDIA GeForce 9500 GT and no image.

When I connect Apple Thunderbolt monitor to PC the image does not load up onto monitor.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Specifications on the cable are?

Comment: The 9500 GT Mac edition [claims to only have DVI outputs](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-9500-gt-mac-edition.c2330) how exactly are you connecting it? Most of [the Thunderbolt adapters I know of for PC](https://amzn.eu/d/0BAvjkh) take in DisplayPort or something similar and package that up into a Thunderbolt port output.

Comment: My apologies for mis information. I have since pulled the video card from my PC and identified the card as the NVIDIA Gforce 120.

Comment: My apologies for mis information. I have since pulled the video card from my PC and identified the card as the NVIDIA Gforce 120. (The Card has both DVI and MDP)

My error error was not identifying the card before placing in PC. When in the PC, device manager identified the card as the GeForce 9500 GT.

Note: When i came accross the the Thunderbolt monitor it was connected to a MacPro utilizing the monitors thunderbolt connector to the Cards MDP connector. leaving me to believe i could pull the card from the MacPro and place it on my PC. No Luck.